# force String to be of a certain struct type in func params in swift

Tags: swift, struct

I have a very simple setup I am doing as a learning experience but I can't figure out how to pass a struct property into a function where the struct property is just a string. I know I can make the func take a String in the arguments, but I want it to be forced to be a valid option from my struct.
First I'll show the code I have now, and then how I am thinking I want it to work...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    struct Notification {
        struct Category {
            static let achievement = "achievement"
            static let reminder = "reminder"
        }
        struct Action {
            static let readLater = "readtLater"
            static let showDetails = "showDetails"
            static let cancel = "cancel"
        }
    }

    private func scheduleNotification(_ delay: Int, type: Notification.Category, title: String, message: String) {
        //setup notification here
    }
```

The problem with that is, when I try to call it with a specific type, like so...

```
scheduleNotification(10, .achievement, "Test", "Test message")
```

It gives me an error saying..

> Member 'achievement' in 'ViewController.Notification.Category'
>   produces result of type 'String', but context expects
>   'ViewController.Notification.Category'

Is it possible to force that param type of String to be a valid option from in the Notification.Category struct?
I have seen other functions where you can pass in a .[something] as a param, so I think it is, but I have no idea how to make it happen. I don't want to just use String as the argument, because then it could be literally anything, I want it to be a valid option in the struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use an enum?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    struct Notification {
        enum Category {
            case achievement
            case reminder
        }
        struct Action {
            static let readLater = "readtLater"
            static let showDetails = "showDetails"
            static let cancel = "cancel"
        }
    }

    private func scheduleNotification(_ delay: Int, type: Notification.Category, title: String, message: String) {
      //setup notification here
    }
}


  scheduleNotification(10, .achievement, "Test", "Test message")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up doing an enum with string value so I could use rawValue everywhere I needed the string representation